# How to use rsyslog to log files from client to server

Tags: rsyslog

I've setup an rsyslog server which accepts log information from clients.

I can successfully receive syslog messages however **I'm interested in logging a number of files too**.

Here is what my client looks like:

```
$ModLoad imfile

$InputFileName /var/log/drew-error.log
$InputFileTag drew:
$InputFileStateFile stat-drew-error
$InputFileSeverity error
$InputRunFileMonitor

$InputFilePollInterval 1
```

I'm not sure exactly what to put in my server config. Ideally I'd like the server to output something like this:

`/var/log/remote/$HOSTNAME/drew-error.log`

Am I going about this the right way? **Is this reasonable to try to achieve?**

Best Case Scenario: *I'd like to be able to update the files I'm watching on the client, without having to reconfigure the server. If that's not possible, or too hard, I can probably work around a hard-coded solution.*

### What I've tried

So far I've tried a few configurations for the server (though I feel they're not the right solution/approach):

```
$template syslog, "/var/log/remote/%hostname%/%programname%/%$year%%$month%%$day%/syslog"
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          ?syslog
```

and

```
$template DrewTemplate,"/var/log/remote-DREWAPP-%HOSTNAME%.log"
if $programname == 'drew:' then -?DrewTemplate
& ~

$template PerHostLog,"/var/log/remote-%HOSTNAME%.log"
if $fromhost-ip startswith '1.2.' then -?PerHostLog
& ~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to check the $programname (which gets populated with the value from $InputFileTag on the client for each file you monitor).

### Client Configuration

On the client, create your file monitor(s), and make sure $InputFileTag starts with 'file-'. Here is an example with log files foo and bar:

```
######################### START /var/log/foo.log
$InputFileName /var/log/foo.log
$InputFileTag file-foo:
$InputFileStateFile stat-foo
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputRunFileMonitor
######################### END /var/log/foo.log

######################### START /var/log/bar.log
$InputFileName /var/log/bar.log
$InputFileTag file-bar:
$InputFileStateFile stat-bar
$InputFileSeverity info
$InputRunFileMonitor
######################### END /var/log/bar.log
```

### Server Configuration

And then on the server, check that $programname starts with 'file-' (as should be the case for all of your file monitors, but not for any of the standard syslog messages). Here is an example:

```
$template FileTemplate,"/var/log/remote-%HOSTNAME%-%programname%.log"
if $programname startswith 'file-' then -?FileTemplate
& ~
```

- This solution checks to see if the $programname starts with 'file-'
- As long as you have control over how you label $InputFileTag (on the client) this solution works quite well
- The template uses programname and hostname to keep file names unique on the server
- The & ~ makes sure this syslog message doesn't get processed further down in the config
- This solution provides ONE configuration on the server that doesn't need to be updated each time you add a new file monitor on the client.