# how to forward log file or filtered message contents using rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog

I am trying to filter out logs from journalctl so that matched logs can be forwarded to remote rsys server.

`/var/log/custom` log is getting constructed properly from the filer but not able to forward it to the remote server.

I have referred below links

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37034439/rsyslog-filtering-and-forwarding

[How to use rsyslog to log files from client to server](https://serverfault.com/questions/581714/how-to-use-rsyslog-to-log-files-from-client-to-server)

[How to forward specific log file outside of /var/log with rsyslog to remote server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/396136/how-to-forward-specific-log-file-outside-of-var-log-with-rsyslog-to-remote-serv)
and

[Rsyslog: From a custom log file, Forward only the messages matching a pattern](https://serverfault.com/questions/810448/rsyslog-from-a-custom-log-file-forward-only-the-messages-matching-a-pattern)

However not able to achieve my goal.

This is my rsyslog.conf, am I missing something?

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#            For more information see
#            /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html
#
#  Default logging rules can be found in /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf

# Configure the LocalHostName, so that syslogs carry the hostname instead of the alias.
$LocalHostName nd2bwa4drc01v.eng.mobilephone.net

#################
#### MODULES ####
#################

module(load="imuxsock") # provides support for local system logging
module(load="imklog")   # provides kernel logging support


###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################
# Use traditional timestamp format.
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

# Filter duplicated messages
$RepeatedMsgReduction on

# Set the default permissions for all log files.
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog

# Where to place spool and state files
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog


######################
#### Ad-Hoc rules ####
######################
# Log anything [except kern/mail/cron/local2(snmp)/local7(boot)/local5(calea)]
# of level info or higher.
# Don't log private authentication messages!
#
# Filtering out harmless but repetitive messages
#
:msg, contains, "shim containerd-shim started"    stop
:msg, contains, "shim reaped"    stop
:msg, contains, "ignoring event"    stop
:msg, contains, "DEBUG"    stop

# Logging rule
#
#:msg, contains, "logged in over ssh from" @192.168.11.71:6514
#:msg, contains, "Logged out ssh" @192.168.11.71:6514
#if $msg contains 'logged in over ssh from' then @192.168.11.71:6514
:msg, contains, "logged in over ssh from" /var/log/custom
:msg, contains, "Logged out ssh" /var/log/custom
*.info;auth.none;authpriv.none;kern.none;mail.none;cron.none;local2.none;local7.none;local5.none   /var/log/syslog
daemon.*                      -/var/log/daemon.log
mail.*                        -/var/log/mail.log
mail.warn                     /var/log/mail.warn
#kern.*                        -/var/log/kern.log
kern.debug                    stop

*.=debug;\
  auth,authpriv.none;\
  news.none;mail.none         /var/log/debug

# Everybody gets emergency messages
*.emerg                                                 :omusrmsg:*

# Save news errors of level crit and higher in a special file.
uucp,news.crit                                          /var/log/spooler

# Save boot messages also to boot.log
local7.*                                                /var/log/boot.log

# capture WARN logs in a separate file
#*.warn;local5.none                                      /var/log/warn.log

###############################
##### Begin forwarding rule ###
###############################
# Forward to contol-0/1 (rsylog-proxy) VIP
#
auth.info,authpriv.* /var/log/secure
auth.info,authpriv.* @192.168.11.71:6514
#:msg, contains, "logged in over ssh from" @192.168.11.71:6514
*.info;auth.none;authpriv.none;mail.none;cron.none;local2.none;local7.debug;local5.none @192.168.11.71:6514

##### End of the forwarding rule ###
```